# How to fix webmail not working in a VPS with Plesk

Tags: email, plesk

I have a VPS server running Ubunutu16 + Plesk.
Webmail Roundcube starts without issues.
I created one email account admin@mydomain.com
I can send only the mail from admin@mydomain.com to admin
Sending mail to the server and from the server to my gmail and other accounts are not working. 
in the /var/log/maillog I see timeouts like below.

```
Jan 11 19:20:13 localhost dovecot: service=imap, user=admin@mydomain.de, ip=[127.0.0.1]. Logged out rcvd=50, sent=512
Jan 11 19:21:13 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@mydomain.de>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1909, TLS, session=<sh4nmTN/7q9/AAAB>
Jan 11 19:21:13 localhost dovecot: service=imap, user=admin@mydomain.de, ip=[127.0.0.1]. Logged out rcvd=50, sent=512
Jan 11 19:22:13 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@mydomain.de>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1914, TLS, session=<adS6nDN/8q9/AAAB>
Jan 11 19:22:13 localhost dovecot: service=imap, user=admin@mydomain.de, ip=[127.0.0.1]. Logged out rcvd=50, sent=512
Jan 11 19:23:13 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@mydomain.de>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1918, TLS, session=<+EtOoDN/+q9/AAAB>
Jan 11 19:23:13 localhost dovecot: service=imap, user=admin@mydomain.de, ip=[127.0.0.1]. Logged out rcvd=50, sent=512
Jan 11 19:24:13 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@mydomain.de>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1922, TLS, session=<ltLhozN/ArB/AAAB>
Jan 11 19:24:13 localhost dovecot: service=imap, user=admin@mydomain.de, ip=[127.0.0.1]. Logged out rcvd=50, sent=512
Jan 11 19:25:13 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@mydomain.de>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1931, TLS, session=<oWl1pzN/BrB/AAAB>
Jan 11 19:25:13 localhost dovecot: service=imap, user=admin@mydomain.de, ip=[127.0.0.1]. Logged out rcvd=50, sent=512
Jan 11 19:25:37 localhost postfix/qmgr[1235]: 22EA062BD2: from=<admin@mydomain.de>, size=613, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 11 19:25:37 localhost postfix/qmgr[1235]: 50E9362CEB: from=<admin@mydomain.de>, size=599, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 11 19:26:07 localhost postfix/smtp[1971]: connect to mx00.emig.gmx.net[212.227.15.9]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 11 19:26:07 localhost postfix/smtp[1972]: connect to mx00.emig.gmx.net[212.227.15.9]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 11 19:26:13 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@mydomain.de>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=2034, TLS, session=<OB8JqzN/HrB/AAAB>
Jan 11 19:26:13 localhost dovecot: service=imap, user=admin@mydomain.de, ip=[127.0.0.1]. Logged out rcvd=50, sent=512
root@localhost:/var/log# telnet alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

After I have set MX record in DNS records error disappeared.